# Scraping value of website after script has run on that website and redirects me

Tags: javascript, python, html, redirect, screen-scraping

I want to fill in some values and then click a button, this will run some javascript on the website I'm doing this on that will show me the data based on the value of which it is that day. The output will be available in plain html.

When I click this button that will show the data of the script ran, it redirects me, same site but difference is what's behind the `/` of the url and show me the output of the script

I've found that Selenium API can do the entering of values and click the button.

But now, and this could be due to my beginners understanding of python/programming in general and how websites with python when being redirected and how it works when the data shown is formulated by a script, but I want to know if or how I can then pull or request that url and/or data the script has outputted. To then scrape that specific output.

Probably important to know is that when the script has run and I copy the URL that has the data I want to scrape and paste it into another tab it redirects me the the form for putting in some values to run that script. Which puts me back to where I started.

Is this even possible with python or an API, if so, how?

I want the script to do this.

This is the website so you can try and see for yourself;
https://www.budgetthuis.nl/energie/

Fill in those textboxes with the values circled;
[enter values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8srYO.jpg)

Then when clicked on "bereken aanbod", I want it to copy the circled output of these values and put it into a text/excel file;
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJxo8.jpg)

Is this feasible in python? Do I need to worry about it redirecting me for the output, how does it work? I know it is a JavaScript that calculates the output.

I want a script to do this automatically, because the output varies and I want to use that data.

Comment: Sorry i dont understand all , cause of my sad english , but i have already make a selenium script for download all my facebook image once , so if we can go step by step ( like i have done to acheived my task) i think i can help u

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do the whole scrape with selenium? Or transfer rendered html browser.page_source

Comment: I've updated the post with pictures and a link